# How to change the label text dynamically in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

HTML:

```
<center><p id="drag1" class="ui-widget-content"> Paragraph</p></center>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-sortable" ><ol></ol></div>

<div class="change">
<form>
Change title: <input type="text" id="titleName" />
<input type="button" value="ok" id="save" />
</form>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$("#droppable").append('<li class="ui-state-default">' + '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' +
  '<div class="address" id="InputsWrapper_2' + addressFieldCount + '">' +
'<p>' + '<label class="add">Address:' + addressFieldCount + '</label>' + '<br>'  +
     '<textarea type="text" name="myaddress[]" id="field_' + addressFieldCount + '" placeholder="Address' + addressFieldCount + '" />' +
 '<button class="removeclass1">x</button>' +
   '</p>' + '<br>' + '</div>' + '</li>');

$('.add').click(function(){      
  var labelAddress = $('.add'+addressFieldCount+'');
$(".change").find('input[type="text"]').val($(".add").text()).show().focus();
});

$(".change").focusout(function() {

$("#droppable").find('label').text(this.value).show();
 $('.add').text($('#titleName').val()).val;
   });
```

When there are two or more text areas already dragged and dropped in the #droppable with label address1 and address2 and I want to change only the label address1 to the value typed in the textbox. how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming `this.value` holds the textbox value (if you are inside an event handler that belongs to the textbox for example)

if you just want the first label, you can use `.eq(0)` or `.first()`:

```
$("#droppable").find('label').eq(0).text(this.value).show();
```

note however, that `.find()` only searches the first level of child elements. if you need to search deeper, you can use the selector `$(<what>,<where>)`:

```
$('label', $("#droppable")).eq(0).text(this.value).show();
```

and of course, if `address1` is an id/class/whatever, you can just search like this:

```
$('.address1', $("#droppable")).eq(0).text(this.value).show();
$('#address1', $("#droppable")).eq(0).text(this.value).show();
$('label[name=address1]', $("#droppable")).eq(0).text(this.value).show();
```

**UPDATE:**

i believe this is what you tried to achieve, explanation in the comments:

```js
$(function () {
    var addressFieldCount = 5;

    for (i = 1; i <= addressFieldCount; i++) {
        $("#droppable").append('<li class="ui-state-default">' + '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' +
            '<div class="address" id="InputsWrapper_2' + i + '">' +
            '<p>' + '<label class="add">Address:' + i + '</label>' + '<br>' +
            '<textarea type="text" name="myaddress[]" id="field_' + i + '" placeholder="Address' + i + '" />' +
            '<button class="removeclass1">x</button>' +
            '</p>' + '<br>' + '</div>' + '</li>');
    }


    $('.add').click(function () {
        //we save the index of the selected address. since we clicked the label, going
        //up 3 parents will get us the address div element and we store it's index somwhere safe
        $(".change").data("selectedAddress", $(this).parent().parent().parent().index());
        //since we are in the add's click handler, we can reference the current
        //add lable using $(this)
        $(".change").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text()).show().focus();
    });

    $(".change #titleName").focusout(function () {
        //first we retrieve the index of the address element that we stored earlier
        var selectedAddress = $(".change").data("selectedAddress");
        //next we retrieve the new title:
        var newTitle = $(this).val();
        //the next condition is to avoid changing the titles if you dont click an address first
        if (selectedAddress >= 0) {
            //since every address element only has 1 label, we can safely assume that if we 
            //use the address index, we will get the corresponding label
            $('label', $("#droppable")).eq(selectedAddress).text(newTitle).show();
        }
        //clear the textbox after we change the title
        $(this).val("");
        //clear selected address id
        $(".change").data("selectedAddress", "-1");

    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<center>
  <p id="drag1" class="ui-widget-content">Paragraph</p>
</center>
<div id="droppable" class="ui-sortable">
</div>
<div class="change">
  <form>Change title:
    <input type="text" id="titleName" />
    <input type="button" value="ok" id="save" />
  </form>
</div>
```

and here is a <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/afLztru2/)**</kbd> for convenience

Comment: Thanks for replying! I want only the text of one label to change at a time.

Comment: @jvf hold on, im writing you an example :)

Comment: It can can be address5 also. address1, address2, address3, etc are all dynamically generated labels

Comment: @jvf yes thats what ive figured later, i am writing you a fixed example based on your code

Comment: @jvf there. if you have any questions, feel free to ask

Comment: Thanks it worked! but how to modify the code if <ol> is added in html code  <div id="droppable" class="ui-sortable" ><ol></ol></div>

Comment: it will work exactly the same, just the `Index` is shifted 1 up because of the extra `<ol>` element, so decrease the index once you retrieve it using `.index()-1`. unless you need to append the address into the `<ol>` in which case simply change it to `$("#droppable ol").append()`

Comment: If there are textbox and button and more elements with textboxFieldcount, buttonfieldcount..how to take care of the index?

Comment: @jvf it doesnt matter. i changed it to a `for` loop just for convenience so i wont need to type the same code 5 times :). the addresses will still have same index. the `index()` has nothing to do with the `textboxFieldcount`, the `index()` returns their index in the parent element. for example, if the droppable box has 4 elements, the `<ol>` will have index 0, the 1st address will have index `1`, and so on..

Comment: You can find lots of examples on jquey website

Comment: @ banana can you help me with the new question that I have posted?